# PHP / JS - pass select data to a php variable in "loaded" file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a select on a page, and I need to take the value and pass that to a php variable which is loaded via another file using jquery.load.

```
$("[name=quote_storage_location]").on("change", function() {
    var storenamechange = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        data: {storename: storenamechange },
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
        }
    });

    $("#size-select").load("select.php");
});
```

PHP file

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['storename'])){
    $location = $_POST['storename'];
    echo $location;
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

If I alert / console.log the JS variable then I get the desired answer but when the PHP file is loaded I get fail

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: Is the script at the bottom the one being run with `$.ajax` or `.load()`?

Comment: How are you trying to pass a variable from one script to another?

Answer (score 2):

your ajax call does not specify the request type (POST, GET, PUT etc), so it is defaulting to GET. Then your php is setup in such a way that weird things happen

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['storename'])){ // $_REQUEST contains contents of $_GET and $_POST
 $location = $_POST['storename']; // but since ajax call is using GET, the POST variable is empty
 echo $location;
} else {
 echo 'fail';
}
```

this should work

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['storename'])){
 $location = $_REQUEST['storename'];
 echo $location;
} else {
 echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, not sure why my post type was removed and adding that back didn't solve it.

Comment: do print_r($_POST);print_r($_GET); print_r($_REQUEST);